# Get control id withing the FormCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Html editor (in asp.net mvc4) to show the value as below

```
Html.EditorFor(m=> model.Name, null, new { id = "id", name = "na" })
```

when the save button clicks in the coroller method is like this.

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

When that EditorFor coming to this controller it's key always show as the Name. Can't I get id or name property from the key.
In my original code I need to add editofor withing a loop with dynamic ids.

Comment: A form only posts back the `name/value` pairs of its successful controls and you `EditorFor()` generates `<input name="Name" .. />` The `id` of a form control is not sent in the request, but you not generating `id="id"` in any case - look at the html your generating (the 3rd parameter is `additionalViewData`)

Comment: If you want to generate `name="na"`, then its `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, null, "na")` (but the `id` will also be `id="na"`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke , you are right .A form only posts back the name/value pairs  .

Comment: I'm using this editorfor within a loop in the view
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
@Html.EditorFor(m=> model.Name, null, new { id = "id", name = "na" })
}

from my controller method I need to identify each editorfor created from the view.